# Get all duplicates from the array without traversing more than 1

Tags: c#, .net

I have a integer array list int[] marks = {2,3,4,5,4,5,6,2,9};

I want to get all duplicate in this list and the array shold traverse only once.
No inbuild function should use becasue every inbuild function also traverse for every serch.

Expected result should be 2,4,5

Comment: This forum is for practical solutions.  Insisting upon "no inbuilt functions" stinks of homework, or useless academia.  Try codereview.SE.  And read the SO faq - if this were a legitimate question you are still missing some elements - like what you have already tried.

Comment: @Dan-o Homework in itself is fine (although the OP should state this is what it is).  But the question is otherwise poor, I agree. -1

Comment: It could be ok question if you show your approach that you don't like... But simply saying "every inbuild function also traverse for every search" is not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as long as the qualification is that you can only traverse THIS list once, you could create two more lists, 1 non-duplicates and 1 duplicates.

Iterate through the input list, and then check if the non-duplicates has the int.  If not, then add it, if so, then add it to the dups if it doesn't already contain it.  In the end, the dups should have your requested result.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] marks = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 2, 9 };
Dictionary<int, bool> flags = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>();

for (int index = 0; index < marks.Length; index++)
{
    if (flags.ContainsKey(marks[index])) result.Add(marks[index]);
    else flags.Add(marks[index], true);
}
```

Comment: flags.ContainsKey() is an inbuild funciton and that perform traversing on the collection.

Comment: @SandeepKumar: When you deal with the n-th element in `marks`, you need to know if it's a duplicate or not. Then you need to check some container to get the result. `flags.ContainsKey` doesn't perform traversing on the whole collection, but part of it, which is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [find Duplicates in linear time](http://harithimanshu.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/finding-duplicate-value-in-unsorted-array-in-linear-time/)